# How save Tensorflow model in protobuf format?

Tags: python, opencv, tensorflow, neural-network

Please, help me with my problem. I want to save my neural network in protobuf (pb) format for OpenCV DNN. In input I have 3 files: .meta, .data, .index. As output I need to .pb and .pbtxt files.

Code, for example:

```
train_data = np.load(TEST_PACK)

tf.reset_default_graph()
convnet = input_data(shape=[None, SIZE, SIZE, 3], name='input')


convnet = conv_2d(convnet, 32, 10, activation='relu')
convnet = max_pool_2d(convnet, 30)

convnet = conv_2d(convnet, 64, 10, activation='relu')
convnet = max_pool_2d(convnet, 10)

convnet = conv_2d(convnet, 128, 5, activation='relu')
convnet = max_pool_2d(convnet, 5)

convnet = conv_2d(convnet, 64, 5, activation='relu')
convnet = max_pool_2d(convnet, 5)

convnet = conv_2d(convnet, 32, 5, activation='relu')
convnet = max_pool_2d(convnet, 5)

convnet = fully_connected(convnet, 1024, activation='relu')
convnet = dropout(convnet, 0.8)

convnet = fully_connected(convnet, 3, activation='softmax')

convnet = regression(convnet, optimizer='adam', learning_rate=LR, loss='categorical_crossentropy', name='targets')


model = tflearn.DNN(convnet, tensorboard_dir='log')

print('model loaded!')

train = train_data[:-500]
test = train_data[-500:]

X = np.array([i[0] for i in train]).reshape(-1,SIZE,SIZE,3)
Y = [i[1] for i in train]

test_x = np.array([i[0] for i in test]).reshape(-1,SIZE,SIZE,3)
test_y = [i[1] for i in test]

model.fit({'input': X}, {'targets': Y}, n_epoch=5, validation_set=({'input': test_x}, {'targets': test_y}), 
          snapshot_step=500, show_metric=True, run_id=MODEL_NAME)
```

I am new to neural networks & apologize if I asked nonsense))

Answer (score 0):

The below function will freeze your model and create ".pb" file.

```
def freeze_model(sess, logs_path, latest_checkpoint, model, pb_file_name, freeze_pb_file_name):
    """
    :param sess     : tensor-flow session instance which creates the all graph information
    :param logs_path: string
                      directory path where the checkpoint files are stored
    :param latest_checkpoint: string
                              checkpoint file path
    :param model: model instance for extracting the nodes explicitly
    :param pb_file_name: string
                         Name of trainable pb file where the graph and weights will be stored
    :param freeze_pb_file_name: string
                                Name of freeze pb file where the graph and weights will be stored
    """
    print("logs_path =", logs_path)
    tf.train.write_graph(sess.graph.as_graph_def(), logs_path, pb_file_name)
    input_graph_path = os.path.join(logs_path, pb_file_name)
    input_saver_def_path = ""
    input_binary = False
    input_checkpoint_path = latest_checkpoint
    output_graph_path = os.path.join(logs_path, freeze_pb_file_name)
    clear_devices = False
    output_node_names = ",".join(model.nodes)
    restore_op_name = "save/restore_all"
    filename_tensor_name = "save/Const:0"
    initializer_nodes = ""
    freeze_graph.freeze_graph(input_graph_path,
                              input_saver_def_path,
                              input_binary,
                              input_checkpoint_path,
                              output_node_names,
                              restore_op_name,
                              filename_tensor_name,
                              output_graph_path,
                              clear_devices,
                              initializer_nodes)
```

`model.nodes` is a list of tensor nodes. I think you can make `output_node_names` an empty string: `output_node_names = ""`

Comment: Thank you, but I have problem with found DNN attribute in model
AttributeError: 'DNN' object has no attribute 'nodes'

Comment: And new trouble... Result frozen file do not contains any information
logs_path = log
INFO:tensorflow:Restoring parameters from reshape.ckpt
INFO:tensorflow:Froze 0 variables.
INFO:tensorflow:Converted 0 variables to const ops.